# zeros of Bessel function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots, bessel-functions

Let's denote $J_\alpha$ the Bessel functions of first kind, satisfying the equation
$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-\alpha^2)y=0$$
Now consider its zeros, there are $2$ questions.

> 1. For the case $\alpha=0$, find the smallest $l$, such that when a zero point $x$ given, there's another zero in $(x,x+l)$
> 2. For the case $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, prove that in any open interval of length $\pi$, there are at most a zero point in it.

I googled the asymptotic behavior of $J_\alpha$, which implies $l\geq\pi$. And then I can do nothing.

There are some series expansion of zero point in terms of $\alpha$. If you use this, please denote the source so that I can learn from it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second question see **Sturm Separation Theorem,** (valid for Sturm-Liouville differential equations in general), in particular the last page of [this document](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~siva/ma41707/ode8.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, in fact, it solves both of my problem. You can post it as an answer. @JeanMarie

Comment: In case whatever you're working on requires more information about zeros of Bessel functions, Chapter XV in [**A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521483913) by George Neville Watson (1944, 2nd edition) has a lot of information.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know much about Bessel functions, and the only reason I know about the stuff in Watson's book is from some historical investigations I made back in 2006 about the nature of the solutions to the transcendental equation $\tan x = x$ -- see the [sci.math thread I began on 19 January 2006](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/1KOaZXdFAG4/m/TcyHql37MA4J), especially the post I made on on [28 February 2006](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/1KOaZXdFAG4/m/yR1pqJ1xDoYJ) **(continued)**

Comment: and (in another sci.math thread) the post I made on [26 April 2006](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GbT6ch7IEPY/m/TcUPAe3JtnQJ). I never did get around to writing up all the stuff I found about the solutions to $\tan x = x$ (which I mentioned at least twice in 2006 sci.math posts; I've collected a lot more since then also), but I did present that MAA talk on 8 April 2006 ([abstract](http://sections.maa.org/iowa/db/index.php/proposal/viewPublic/144) and [conference program](http://sections.maa.org/iowa/history/scannedDocs/2005-06/05-06mtg2006IAMathMeetingScheduleApril2006.pdf)).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro Thanks for sharing this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bessel differential equation is a particular case of a Sturm-Liouville equation.

It is true that $J_0$ has rather specific properties ; it can be placed apart with a behavior rather close to sine function.

For the general case, there is an important result called **Sturm Separation Theorem** which you will find explained with the particular case of Bessel differential equation treated as well [here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/%7Esiva/ma41707/ode8.pdf).

Comment: Actually it's Sturm Comparison Theorem in the material you given solves my question.

Comment: You are right...